# EclipseLink JPA Primary Key with Custom Default Value

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I have a table in my SQL Server database where the primary key field is defined with `NEWID()` as the default value. The expectation is client need not pass the primary key field value and the SQL server will handle it.

While defining my model class at JPA I have to define this ID field with a generation type.  I tried `IDENTITY`, `TABLE` and `SEQUENCE` Generator. Unfortunately I am getting an error as

```
Exception Description: Error preallocating sequence numbers.  
The sequence table information is not complete..
```

My Persistence. XML is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="LOB_Webservice" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.xyz.lob.model.jpa.OrderDetail</class>
    <class>com.xyz.lob.model.jpa.OrderHeader</class>
    <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode> 
    <properties>
        <property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="org.eclipse.persistence"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=LOB_INT" /> 
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa" /> 
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="*******" /> 
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>       
        <property name="eclipselink.sharedCache.mode" value="None"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.cache-statements" value="false" />  
        <property name="eclipselink.query-results-cache" value="false"/>    
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.exceptions" value="true"/>  
        <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="static"/>       
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

My Model class is as below

```
@Entity
public class OrderHeader implements Serializable {
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)    
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="OrderId")
    private String orderId;        
    ...
}
```

Comment: You need to use something like Identity, as the other strategies have JPA look up and assign the sequence number in the insert statement, while Identity allows it to get the value from the database after the insert.  See http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/PrimaryKey#Using_Identity_Columns  for a simple example, and show the complete error you are getting with IDENTITY.  You might also try specifying the database platform to be user it is using the right one: http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/p_target_database.htm

Comment: Sorry, the above comment was made not realizing NEWID() means you are using a uniqueidentifier database type, and I didn't see the string in the entity.  You will need to build your own NativeSequence instance and override getGeneratedValue to deal with Strings instead of a Number.  See the first link for building a custom strategy in the comment above.

Answer (score 7):

Hi @Joe2013 Not sure if is still an issue but when using Table Generators AND you did not specified for Eclipse Link to generate the schema based on your object model, you must manually create the table AND also insert the rows for the corresponding generators and their initial values.
Otherwise it will not work and you will get the error you mentioned.

Comment: The solution is to create a table named sequence and populate with:               (SEQ_GEN_TABLE,0). The create statement: CREATE TABLE `sequence` (
  `SEQ_NAME` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `SEQ_COUNT` decimal(38,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SEQ_NAME`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Answer (score 3):

I have provided custom and default Sequence ID Generator examples as below.

**Use Custom Sequence ID Generator (EclipseLink only)**

Define Custom Sequence class

```
package org.phstudy.sequence;

public class MyNewIDSequence extends Sequence implements SessionCustomizer {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6308907478094680131L;
    public MyNewIDSequence() {
        super();
    }

    public MyNewIDSequence(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public void customize(Session session) throws Exception {
        MyNewIDSequence sequence = new MyNewIDSequence("mynewid");
        session.getLogin().addSequence(sequence);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGeneratedValue(Accessor accessor, AbstractSession writeSession, String seqName) {
        DataReadQuery query = new DataReadQuery("select NEWID()");
        query.setResultType(DataReadQuery.VALUE);
        return writeSession.executeQuery(query);
    }

    @Override
    public Vector getGeneratedVector(Accessor accessor, AbstractSession writeSession, String seqName, int size) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnect() { }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnect() { }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldAcquireValueAfterInsert() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldUsePreallocation() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldUseTransaction() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Register custom sequence in persistence.xml

```
<persistence ...>
    <persistence-unit ...>
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider> 
        <properties>
            ...
            <property name="eclipselink.session.customizer" value="org.phstudy.sequence.MyNewIDSequence"/>
            ...
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Add Sequence Annotation with custom sequence name

```
@Entity
public class CustomSequence {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "mynewid")
    private String id;
    ...
}
```

**Use Default Sequence ID Generator (JPA, EclipseLink, Hibernate)**

Please enable automatic schema generation or create table for storing ID manually when using `Table`, `Sequence` or `IDENTITY` ID Generation.

opt#1. Enable automatic schema generation

```
<persistence ...>
    <persistence-unit ...>
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider> 
        <properties>
            ...
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
            ...
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

opt#2. Create table for storing ID manually

Define Sequence in your entity

```
@SequenceGenerator(name="Emp_Gen", sequenceName="Emp_Seq")
@Id @GeneratedValue(generator="Emp_Gen") 
private int getId;
```

SQL script to create sequence

```
CREATE SEQUENCE Emp_Seq
     MINVALUE 1
     START WITH 1
     INCREMENT BY 50 //allocation size
```

Comment: I did all these.  Unfortunately JPA Is not accepting them.  I don't have a SEQUENCE in the database and hence I cannot specify the  sequence name

Comment: Could you provide your persistence.xml?

Comment: hi @Joe2013, I didn't see you Enable automatic schema generation nor set up a SEQUENCE in your code.

I have edited my answer and add example to enable automatic schema generation and set up a SEQUENCE.

Comment: Hi @study..   I did exactly what you said (option 1). it gave me an error/warning as  Identity column 'OrderId' must be of data type int, bigint, smallint, tinyint, or decimal or numeric with a scale of 0, and constrained to be nonnullable. Description: Error preallocating sequence numbers.  The sequence table information is not complete.

Comment: As i said earlied, my primary key in the database is a uniqueidentifier and it is defined with a default values as NEWID()

Comment: It won't work with a string, as the default sequence generators expect to get a number back instead.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding of your problem. This is not answer, I will fix it later.

Comment: Hi @Joe2013, I have improved my answer :)