# Database error: Error preallocating sequence numbers

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jdbc, eclipselink

My Java Servlet application which uses JPA and EclipseLink to connect to a MySQL 5 database throws the following exception when trying to access the database. What does that mean?

```
[EL Warning]: 2020-07-20 19:47:28.437--UnitOfWork(363953304)--Exception [EclipseLink-4011] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Exception Description: Error preallocating sequence numbers.  The sequence table information is not complete.
Exception [EclipseLink-4011] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Exception Description: Error preallocating sequence numbers.  The sequence table information is not complete.
```

Edit #1: the database is empty and was created using an SQL script generated by mysqldump from a working production database (without including the data).

Edit #2: the sequence table is empty and populating it with something like  `INSERT INTO sequence VALUES ('SEQ_GEN',0);` seems to fix the issue. Maybe someone will like to provide some background information on this.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24439062/4808122)  solve your problem? Do you have the `sequence` table defined?

Comment: @MarmiteBomber no this does not seem to solve my problem, unfortunately. The sequence tables exists in my database.

Comment: You didn't show anything from your setup or how you created the 'sequence', which is Database specific if a sequence, but in this case is just table sequencing. The error points you at the issue, and the answer linked in the comment explicitly states "AND also insert the rows for the corresponding generators and their initial values". You have a sequence table but no entry for the sequence you've specified in JPA hence it is incomplete. table generation would have created that row for you, and is described at https://wiki.eclipse.org/Introduction_to_EclipseLink_JPA_%28ELUG%29#.40TableGenerator

Comment: @Chris yes I initially missed the "AND also insert the rows .."